# How to check if a value exists in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How to check if a value already exists in other array. like in the code below I wanted to check which values of result array are in the portOut array. I am not getting it right. Used Array.asList(result[i]).contains(portOut[i]) but something is wrong...

```
int[] portOut = {4000,4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4008,4009};
int[] result = {4001, 4005, 4003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 

for (int i=0; i< portOut.length; i++){
   if(Arrays.asList(result).contains(portOut[i])){
      System.out.println("out put goes to " + portOut[i] );
   }
   else{
     System.out.println("output of " + portOut[i]+ " will be zero");
      }
   }
```

Comment: portOut[i] == result[i]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is a generic function that takes a parameter of `T... array`, in case of `int[]` the only applicable type is `int[]`, i.e. your list will contain only one element, which is the array if integers. To fix it use boxed primitive types:

```
Integer[] portOut = {4000,4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4008,4009};
Integer[] result = {4001, 4005, 4003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write two for loops and check whether any given element in one array is in the other. So just:

```
for (int i=0; i< portOut.length; i++){
   for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++) {
      //rest of code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (int i=0; i< portOut.length; i++)
   {
     for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++) 
     {
        if(portOut[i]==result[j])
        {
           //result[j] is the required value you want. You can put this into other array.
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that returns a Boolean value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < portOut.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
        if(portOut[i] == result[j])
            return true;

return false;
```